# How can I check a macro's definition or document?

Tags: texdoc, texdef

I am trying to use "texdef" to get a marco/command's definition - but it seems only support a small portion or native marcos.
for example, I use

```
texdef -t latex -f itemize -s -E -F
```

I can get a lot of output, which contains most information i needed. But when I try to check "includegraphics" marco from "graphics" package by same command, I get no useful information returned.

```
texdef -t latex -f includegraphics -s -E
```

So my question is - If I want to check how a macro from a package defined, can I only go through the docs from that package? I use:

```
texdoc graphics
```

Then I search the marcos I want to check.

Any good suggestions? thanks a lot!

Comment: `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{graphicx}\begin{document}\ttfamily\meaning\includegraphics\end{document}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the option `-p <package>` you can search a package. In your case e.g.

```
texdef -t latex -s -p graphicx -f includegraphics
```